# При отправке Ajax формы страница перезагружается

Tags: c#

Есть форма добавления товаров в корзину на сайте.С обычной формой и редериктом она работает.Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при отправке формы сайт не перезагружался поэтому сделал форму ajax.

```
<form action="/Cart/AddToCart" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#results" >
         @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
         <li class="add-to-cart">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-size lg-size btn-pronia-primary" value="Добавить в корзину" />
         </li>
/form>
```

Также пробовал скриптом ,но там нет реакции от слова совсем

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $('#Id').val();
  alert("EnterFulName")
  $('#results').load('@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart")?id='+id)
  });
  });
</script>
```

Сайт закружаетт страницу addtocart ,хотя должен загрузить частичное представление.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос меток хоть, укажите в тегах хотя бы версию asp.net (mvc или core mvc), ajax, jquery и razor.

Comment: а вообще, вот вы атрибуты data-ajax и прочие используете, а библиотеку которая их обрабатывает подключить не забыли?

Comment: кажется, она называется unobtrusive ajax или как-то так